# Permanently add SAP Business One Studio for Microsoft Visual Studio add on to SAP Client menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sapb1

I am developing in SAP Business One Studio for Microsoft Visual Studio (VS2010) and whilst I am able to preview my forms (.b1f) files in the SAP Business One Client, I cannot permanently add them. On logging out of the SAP Business One client and logging back in again, the Visual Studio forms I have added disappear.

Can anyone tell me how to permanently add these to the SAP Business One client menu from VS2010?

I researched this on-line and previous versions of SAP have a Visual Studio wizard, which creates a .rda file from the VS2010 solution, which can be imported to the SAP client but I do not have this wizard in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let people know that we ended up resolving this by adding our B1Studio exe file to the installer project present in the SAP SDK samples, as an Embedded Resource.

Next we created the .ard file using the SAP\Tools\AddOnRegDataGen\AddOnRegDataGen.exe tool. The ard file (add on) can then be added to the SAP client in the Administration->Add ons menu. Hope this helps someone else. No sign of the installation wizard in the Business One Studio for VS2010 and no response from SAP support.